# Communication failing between Kubernetes Nodes and clusterIP

Tags: iptables, kubernetes, flannel

I am evaluating Kubernetes and installed it following [this tutorial](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/getting-started.html) on CentOS 7.2 box and VMware VMs. My environment has one Docker Registry, one Etcd server, one Kube Master and two Kube Nodes. Every single piece of the communication works like a charm, thanks to Flannel and the excellent Kubernetes docs and papers out there. One exception: the communication between one Node to the service's clusterIP.

Some information regarding my environment:

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       NODE
nginx-a2klb   1/1       Running   2          1d        10.200.81.54

$ kubectl get pods/nginx-a2klb -o yaml | grep podIP
  podIP: 10.252.54.2

$ kubectl get svc/nginx -o yaml | grep clusterIP
  clusterIP: 10.254.0.7
```

Trying the communication from `10.200.81.54` (pod's Node):

```
$ curl http://10.254.0.7
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...
```

From `10.200.81.53` (the other Node):

```
$ curl http://10.252.54.2 # podIP
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
...

$ curl http://10.254.0.7 # clusterIP
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.254.0.7:80; Connection timed out
```

Long story short: inside containers the communication always works, from the same node or from other nodes. Using the podIP the communication always works as well. ExternalIP or NodePort always works, even outside the cluster. Using the clusterIP the communication only work from the same VM where the only pod is running, failing from other Nodes or from the Kube Master. Is this behavior expected? What can I do to analyze and fix this?

**Update1**

- Master and Nodes uses systemd to run only the `kubelet`
- Other services (`proxy`, `apiserver`, `scheduler`, etc) run inside privileged containers via `hyperkube`
- Link to details about how I configured [Master](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-master.html) and each [Node](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-workers.html)

**Update2**

The relevant part of `iptables` (note that pod and service IPs changed since the first post):

```
-A PREROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.252.36.0/24 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT" -m mark --mark 0x4d415351 -j MASQUERADE
-A KUBE-SEP-722QG7UQNTPWDFBY -s 10.200.81.52/32 -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:" -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4d415351/0xffffffff
-A KUBE-SEP-722QG7UQNTPWDFBY -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.81.52:443
-A KUBE-SEP-7F6QLYX4EVXMHVGW -s 10.252.45.6/32 -m comment --comment "default/ng:" -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4d415351/0xffffffff
-A KUBE-SEP-7F6QLYX4EVXMHVGW -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/ng:" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.252.45.6:80
-A KUBE-SEP-SFIQGU7OZTZRBGQ6 -s 10.252.45.2/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4d415351/0xffffffff
-A KUBE-SEP-SFIQGU7OZTZRBGQ6 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.252.45.2:53
-A KUBE-SEP-WT6RQUWXRXGAUOJF -s 10.252.45.2/32 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4d415351/0xffffffff
-A KUBE-SEP-WT6RQUWXRXGAUOJF -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.252.45.2:53
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.254.0.114/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/ng: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 80 -j KUBE-SVC-LYRG26ZZO4GOQOI3
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.254.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.254.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.254.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes: cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-SVC-6N4SJQIF3IX3FORG
-A KUBE-SERVICES -m comment --comment "kubernetes service nodeports; NOTE: this must be the last rule in this chain" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A KUBE-SVC-6N4SJQIF3IX3FORG -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:" -j KUBE-SEP-722QG7UQNTPWDFBY
-A KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp" -j KUBE-SEP-WT6RQUWXRXGAUOJF
-A KUBE-SVC-LYRG26ZZO4GOQOI3 -m comment --comment "default/ng:" -j KUBE-SEP-7F6QLYX4EVXMHVGW
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns" -j KUBE-SEP-SFIQGU7OZTZRBGQ6
```

I have fixed this issue adding a route:

```
ip route add 10.254.0.0/24 dev flannel.1
```

`10.254.0.0/24` is my `--service-cluster-ip-range`. This is working but it sounds to me more luck than a real fix. Something else I can check, test or improve in my cluster?

Comment: Cluster IPs are virtual IPs that are managed by kube-proxy configuring IP Tables rules. Can you look at the kube-proxy logs on your two nodes to see if there is anything different? And check the iptables rules that are installed to verify that `10.254.0.7` is being captured.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Both kube-proxy has the same errors, have a look at my Update1. iptables -L is clear on every node, outside the kube-proxy container. Btw this same iptables -L is also clear on my CoreOS boxes where everything works.

Comment: @Hannson Nops. I saw elsewhere that that iptables warnings are normal and I stop investigating the routing problem. After all I don't need routing working outside my containers. I'll update this question if I find a solution. Thanks for asking.